# How to remove 'BODY' tag in parsed xml text?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm a novice programmer. I got a problem with parsing some xml files using python 3 and BeautifulSoup4. That is, Parsed text is shown as

```
"BODY { MARGIN: 0px; FONT-FAMILY: Malgun Gothic; COLOR: #000000; FONT-SIZE: 10pt}P { LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px}LI { LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px} blar - blar - blar "
```

'blar - blar - blar' is the text what i want to parse.

How can i remove that useless words in that text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use regex for this.  If you narrowed the formatting of the string you want down a bit, you could create a nicer regex.

```
import re
text = "BODY { MARGIN: 0px; FONT-FAMILY: Malgun Gothic; COLOR: #000000; FONT-SIZE: 10pt}P { LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px}LI { LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px} blar - blar - blar"
print (re.findall("(?:(?:(.*?)}){3})(.*)",text)[0][1])
```

Here's a regex101 for you to look at:

https://regex101.com/r/m0Q3hL/1